# How To Add List-style-type: "disc" to <p> tag

Tags: css, image, html-lists

This seems like it ought to be ridiculously easy, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

I want to replicate the `<li>` function so the disc image appears to the left, but applied to a

tag

I have this, but it does not show the disc image.

```
.list {
     margin-top: 15px;
     margin-bottom: 15px;
     list-style:disc outside none;
     display:inline; 
     }

<p class="list"><em>And Much, Much More!</em></p>
```

I want to avoid using any graphics to simulate the bullet if at all possible.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 34):

Answer:
display: list-item;

Display must be set to list-item - not inline, and not list!

```
.list {
     list-style:disc outside none;
     display:list-item; 
     }

<p class="list"><em>And Much, Much More!</em></p>
```

Comment: this worked great thank you! was driving me nuts. effing CSS I never would have thought to change the display type

Answer (score 2):

Well, a p is not a list. Why not use `<ul><li>`?

[edit]
Let me elaborate.
The problem is that you set this style on a list, while the disc is shown in the list *items*. A `p` has no items in that sense, so there's nothing to apply the disc to.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Just as you updated this, I realized that it has to be list-item. Setting Display:List-Item makes the disc appear :) - Also the reason I want to replicate <li> without using <ul><li> is because I want to put other <p> tags in between the <li> elements, and on IE7 and below the elements between <li> do not appear. I know, bad syntax. So this will fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Only add following style

```css
display:list-item;
```